# How should I tune my Norwegian-styled hardanger fiddle to play the tune called 'Fanitullen'['The Devil's Tune']?

Tags: tuning, violin

I recently bought a 9 string, Norwegian-styled Hardanger fiddle. I want to learn to play the traditioinal Norwegian tune called 'Fanitullen ['The Devil's Tune'].

Can someone tell how to tune this fiddle to be able to play that tune in its traditional way?

Comment: You can find the tuning on Wikipedia (I can't think of the notes on the top of my head but one is c#). You can use this website to find "Fanitullen" and other music for the instrument, but it's all in Norwegian (and come to think of it some of the sheet music should also tell you about tuning). :D

Answer (score 2):

According to the Norwegian Wikipedia article on Fanitullen, it's usually played with the so called "troll tuning", ie. A-E-A-C#.
http://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fanitullen